# react-hooks/exhaustive-deps for chart data of react chartjs 2

Tags: node.js, react-redux, react-chartjs-2

I am using react chartjs2 for displaying line chart. And the data of chart is updating in useEffect. The chart shows data. And things are workimg. But i get this hooks exhaust deps rule warning:

Line 51:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'chartData'.
Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

But if i add the state chartData then the page freeze because i think its going for infinite loop. The data might be calling continuesly.
The code is:

```
const [chartData, setChartData] = useState({
    labels: [],
    datasets:[]
  });

  useEffect(()=>{
    let oNewChartData = {...chartData};
        oNewChartData.labels = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
        oNewChartData.datasets = [{
                       label: 'Week',
                       borderColor: 'green',
                       fill: false,
                       data: {x:[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],y:[0,1,2,3,4,5]}
                   }
                 ]
        setChartData(oNewChartData);
    }
  },[props]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is because useEffect will trigger when chartData is updated, and you update the chartData in your useEffect, this will cause an infinite loop. My guess is that you have an ESLint that tells you to include this value in your useEffect.

ESLint doesn't know about infinite loops in react